# Moving message from trash to inbox causes message to get lost in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

Thunderbird 38.1.0

When I delete an email message from my inbox it goes to trash folder.  If I try to move it back to the inbox it just disappears.  I can not find it anywhere.  I can move messages from the inbox to other folders and move them back to the inbox with no problem.  I have reproduced this with 2 different email accounts on different systems.  One is running Windows 7 and one is running Windows Server Standard R2.  I also reproduced the problem in a Windows 10 system with one of the email accounts.  I am using imap with Charter.  When I test using Charter on line email, this works properly.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?  Has anyone seen this?

Comment: I have observer **delayed** appearance in new mailbox after copy/move operation **on IMAP accounts**

Comment: I have seen delayed actions also.  However, I have waited days and these items never appear.

Comment: I also have a similar problem.  When I try to move an email from Trash to INBOX, it only stays in the INBOX for about a second, then it shows up in the Trash again.  The account is using IMAP, so I even tried using the mail server's web UI, but as soon as Thunderbird syncs with the server, the email is moved back to the Trash.  I think Thunderbird is seeing some "deleted" flag on the message and moving the message back to the Trash.